# Convesion of curve to mesh makes faces behave strangely?

Tags: uv, bezier-curves, faces

As you can see in the image here, [image: LINK]

the outer ring of faces were converted from a curve into a mesh. I welded the points together and proceeded to paint the texture via zbrush. However, I later realized that the outer mesh does not have the texture. Instead, it's black, or requires a separate texture instead. It doesn't show up on UV mapping either.

[image]

I think this image kinda illustrates the idea better in that you can see that the outer mesh isn't highlighted like the others.

I appreciate any help since I'm rather confused on what it means.

I've also had the problem where the UV map likes to split parts of the mesh which I'd rather preserve. I've even created seams myself but it still wants to create extra seams. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Uploading the .blend will help checking what the problem is.

Comment: It's nsfw so I don't think that's allowed. And I THINK I may have figured it out via sheer dumb luck. Tq anyway

Comment: However, I do still have the problem that even though they are all the same material, programs like Daz3d still recognizes them as a separate 'surface' for materials

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to join the two objects together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and UV unwrap one more time.

Comment: It's actually joined already but UV unwrapping doesn't seem to 'see' the outer ring

Comment: I seem to have figured out the problem. For some reason, they were both different materials, so Blender considered them separate groups even though they've been merged. This explains why they are different colored. The reason why they don't have the blue outline is because they are not shaded 'sharp' like the others.

Comment: HOWEVER, in Daz3d, it STILL recognizes it as 3 separate bodies for some reason.